# How to process result set after a "SELECT *" Mysql Prepared Statement query using the C api?

Tags: mysql, c, prepared-statement, resultset, libmysql

On the documentation page for https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-stmt-fetch.html.

In the code sample, it mentions that separate outbound parameters have to be declared in order to have access to the columns listed in the SQL query.

Is it possible to run a "SELECT * WHERE column = ?" query via prepared statements only for the WHERE part of the clause and process the result without knowing the SELECT columns ahead of time therefore not declaring them as outbound parameters?

If so, is there an example anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an example which shows that the outbound bind params need to be generated. Shown here in the php -> pdo_mysql extension source code:

php-8.1.12/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c

```
static bool pdo_mysql_stmt_after_execute_prepared(pdo_stmt_t *stmt) {
        pdo_mysql_stmt *S = stmt->driver_data;
        pdo_mysql_db_handle *H = S->H;

#ifdef PDO_USE_MYSQLND
        /* For SHOW/DESCRIBE and others the column/field count is not available before execute. */
        php_pdo_stmt_set_column_count(stmt, mysql_stmt_field_count(S->stmt));
        for (int i = 0; i < stmt->column_count; i++) {
                mysqlnd_stmt_bind_one_result(S->stmt, i);
        }

        S->result = mysqlnd_stmt_result_metadata(S->stmt);
        if (S->result) {
                S->fields = mysql_fetch_fields(S->result);
                /* If buffered, pre-fetch all the data */
                if (H->buffered) {
                        if (mysql_stmt_store_result(S->stmt)) {
                                pdo_mysql_error_stmt(stmt);
                                return false;
                        }
                }
        }
#else
        /* figure out the result set format, if any */
        S->result = mysql_stmt_result_metadata(S->stmt);
        if (S->result) {
                int calc_max_length = H->buffered && S->max_length == 1;
                S->fields = mysql_fetch_fields(S->result);

                php_pdo_stmt_set_column_count(stmt, (int)mysql_num_fields(S->result));
                S->bound_result = ecalloc(stmt->column_count, sizeof(MYSQL_BIND));
                S->out_null = ecalloc(stmt->column_count, sizeof(my_bool));
                S->out_length = ecalloc(stmt->column_count, sizeof(zend_ulong));

                /* summon memory to hold the row */
                for (int i = 0; i < stmt->column_count; i++) {
                        if (calc_max_length && S->fields[i].type == FIELD_TYPE_BLOB) {
                                my_bool on = 1;
                                mysql_stmt_attr_set(S->stmt, STMT_ATTR_UPDATE_MAX_LENGTH, &on);
                                calc_max_length = 0;
                        }
                        switch (S->fields[i].type) {
                                case FIELD_TYPE_INT24:
                                        S->bound_result[i].buffer_length = MAX_MEDIUMINT_WIDTH + 1;
                                        break;
                                case FIELD_TYPE_LONG:
                                        S->bound_result[i].buffer_length = MAX_INT_WIDTH + 1;
                                        break;
                                case FIELD_TYPE_LONGLONG:
                                        S->bound_result[i].buffer_length = MAX_BIGINT_WIDTH + 1;
                                        break;
                                case FIELD_TYPE_TINY:
                                        S->bound_result[i].buffer_length = MAX_TINYINT_WIDTH + 1;
                                        break;
                                case FIELD_TYPE_SHORT:
                                        S->bound_result[i].buffer_length = MAX_SMALLINT_WIDTH + 1;
                                        break;
                                default:
                                        S->bound_result[i].buffer_length =
                                                S->fields[i].max_length? S->fields[i].max_length:
                                                S->fields[i].length;
                                        /* work-around for longtext and alike */
                                        if (S->bound_result[i].buffer_length > H->max_buffer_size) {
                                                S->bound_result[i].buffer_length = H->max_buffer_size;
                                        }
                        }

                        /* there are cases where the length reported by mysql is too short.
                         * eg: when describing a table that contains an enum column. Since
                         * we have no way of knowing the true length either, we'll bump up
                         * our buffer size to a reasonable size, just in case */
                        if (S->fields[i].max_length == 0 && S->bound_result[i].buffer_length < 128 && MYSQL_TYPE_VAR_STRING) {
                                S->bound_result[i].buffer_length = 128;
                        }

                        S->out_length[i] = 0;

                        S->bound_result[i].buffer = emalloc(S->bound_result[i].buffer_length);
                        S->bound_result[i].is_null = &S->out_null[i];
                        S->bound_result[i].length = &S->out_length[i];
                        S->bound_result[i].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
                }

                if (mysql_stmt_bind_result(S->stmt, S->bound_result)) {
                        pdo_mysql_error_stmt(stmt);
                        PDO_DBG_RETURN(0);
                }

                /* if buffered, pre-fetch all the data */
                if (H->buffered) {
                        if (mysql_stmt_store_result(S->stmt)) {
                                pdo_mysql_error_stmt(stmt);
                                PDO_DBG_RETURN(0);
                        }
                }
        }
#endif

        pdo_mysql_stmt_set_row_count(stmt);
        return true;
}
```